# Parsing bash output

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

```
#!/bin/bash

start(){
  printf 'Real IP: %s\n' "$(curl -s ifconfig.co)"
  set -- /etc/openvpn/ovpn_tcp/*.nordvpn.com.tcp.ovpn
  shift $(( RANDOM % $# ))
  screen -S vpn -dm openvpn "$1" # connect
  sleep 5 # wait for connection
  printf 'VPN IP: %s\n' "$(curl -s ifconfig.co)"
}
stop(){
  screen -S vpn -X quit
  pkill -f ovpn
}
status(){
  printf 'Current IP: %s\n' "$(curl -s ifconfig.co)"
}

case "$1" in
start)
    if screen -ls | grep -w vpn &> /dev/null; then
      echo "VPN Already Connected";
      status
    else
      start
    fi
    ;;
stop)
    stop
    ;;
*)
    status
    ;;
esac
```

The previous `bash`script give the following answer in case if `vpn stop` typed.

run of `vpn stop` if there's active `vpn` connection:

```
[root@A ~]# vpn stop
Terminated
```

run of `vpn stop` if there's not active `vpn` connection:

```
[root@A ~]# vpn stop
No screen session found.
Terminated
```

**What I'm looking to achieve is:**

run of `vpn stop`if there's active `vpn` connection:

```
[root@A ~]# vpn stop
VPN Connection Closed Successfully
```

run of `vpn stop` if there's not active `vpn` connection:

```
[root@A ~]# vpn stop
There's No Active VPN Connection to stop it.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check for the exit signal of the stop command:

```bsh
stop(){
  screen -S vpn -X quit >/dev/null 2>&1
  if [ "$?" == 0 ]; then
    echo "VPN Connection Closed Successfully"
  else
    echo "There's No Active VPN Connection to stop it."
  fi

   pids=( $(pgrep -f ovpn) )
   for pid in "${pids[@]}"; do
    if [[ $pid != $$ ]]; then
     kill "$pid"
  fi
done
}
```

Bash will store the exit signal of the last executed command on the `$?` variable.  By standard, any exit signal with value `0` is to be considered as being successful and anything otherwise is a failure.

EDIT: I made a small typo and switched the order of the `>&` redirector.

Comment: the command will check the exit signal of the screen quit command. Can you run the command manually using `screen -S vpn -X quit && echo $?` and say what the output is, please?

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη sorry, I made a small typo and switched the order of the redirector.  You need `>&` instead of `&>`

Comment: Can you run the script with `bash -x vpn stop` and share the output, please?

Comment: Can you run it with a live vpn connection?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93972/discussion-between-fboaventura-and--c).